# Set true/false value to the localStorage using checkbox and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am trying to set if checkbox is checked

```
$localStorage.something.isChecked = true;
```

else

```
$localStorage.something.isChecked = false;
```

it says isChecked is undefined when i defined it

```
$localStorage.something.isChecked = false;
```

the localStorage status changed when checkbox is checked to the true but it does not false when unChecked. please suggest

Comment: can you paster your  checkbox handler code?

Comment: you can do any simple checkbox input

Comment: @James I have posted the answer, is it what you're looking for

Comment: you may need to store boolean or strings with local/session storage as I have not been successfully able to use true/false values. Or you could use JSON

Answer (score 0):

I have done myself Gopinath Shiva

```
$scope.setStorage = function(){
          $localStorage.something.isChecked = $scope.validate;
          alert($localStorage.something.isChecked);
        };

  http://plnkr.co/edit/E1l9sZ0qkiBboNeAdG2j?p=preview
```